# How do I save a web application with JavaScript execution context to be available offline?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, javascript, web-application, save-as

I want not just a page with all dependencies (js/css/images), but also with DOM, execution context, picture inside canvas, offline storage and so on.

Scripts inside the page should not notice the disruption after I load the saved page, unless they keep connection to some server.

It should try to convert web application to stand-alone application.

How do I do it (in some browser)?

For example, saving and opening [this](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/demos/simple_canvas_game/) should lead to game being played in the middle (not from the beginning).

Comment: Answers to existing numerous "How do I save a webpage" questions seem not relevant.

Comment: Even if the execution context is file-persistent, and is entirely local, you will not be able to access it while offline, because the browser resources are tied to the pages online origin-domain so local resources like cookies and temporary files will be inaccessible, as a standard security barrier.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I want something like "save the state of entire browser with the application loaded", but more lightweight. I don't think full context of web application can be saved just as a js file, probably it should be some separate format.